# How does Basecamp crop uploaded user images into a circle?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, basecamp, 37-signals

Does 37signals manipulate the image on the server side? Or do they use javascript to center and crop the user's image on the client-side?

Comment: You may want to look up how to do it with CSS border radius: http://codeitdown.com/css-circles/

Answer (score 1):

It's happening client side with the border-radius CSS rules (in a todo's comment section):

```
img.avatar {
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```